# How to call a function from button click kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I have two activities, `LoginActivity` and `MainActivity`. When I press a button in my `LoginActivity` I want to call a function in `MainActivity`.How can I achieve this?

- MainActivity function*

```
    fun triggerRestart(context: Activity) {
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context.startActivity(intent)
        if (context is Activity) {
            (context as Activity).finish()
        }
        Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)
    }
```

Please give me a proper solution. Thanks

Comment: Activities shouldn't talk to each, each Activity is consider its own separate entry point. Is there a reason you can't run the function in the login activity?

Comment: @Shawn, It's a common practice to store static functions which doesn't access anything of the particular activity it is declared in but are only related to it in its companion object, so it can be re-used through other Activities instead of re-writing it in Activities it is used. Although, the OP can also use extension function on `Activity` but there's nothing wrong in the way it is currently used. Because, in this particular case, `MainActivity` is running or not doesn't matter and it cannot cause a runtime error. This is done to simplify the code and make it easier to understand the code.

Comment: @Shawn I want to run a `function` to clear the app data and the `function` I am running is causing to close my app after clearing app data. that's why I want to restart it back. So I think it is not possible to restart the app with a single `activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do it in Kotlin:

1. **Using Object** - As it is a static function which doesn't access views or data of
   `MainActivity`, you can call it through an `object` of
   `MainActivity` as it need not be the running instance.

   So, you can call it as `MainActivity().triggerRestart()`.
2. **Using Companion Object** - You can also declare the function in Comapnion
   Object of `MainActivity` as

   ```
   Companion object {
       fun triggerRestart(context: Activity) {
           val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
           context.startActivity(intent)
           if (context is Activity) {
               (context as Activity).finish()
           }
           Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)
       }
   }
   ```

   And then can access it as `MainActivity.triggerRestart()`.
3. **Getting instance from Companion Object** - You can get an instance of the MainActivity and then, can access the function through it as:

   ```
   Companion object {
       val instance = MainActivity()

   }

   fun triggerRestart(context: Activity) {
       val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
       context.startActivity(intent)
       if (context is Activity) {
           (context as Activity).finish()
       }
       Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)
   }
   ```

   and then can access it as `MainActivity.instance.triggerRestart()`.

Difference between first and second is that you don't have to unncessarily create an object of `MainActivity` in second way to access a static function.

Difference between second and third is in third, you're accessing the function through an instance of activity passed by the activity itself, unnecessary for static values but important in case you want to access the views/values of **running** instance of the `MainActivity`.

You can further improve the third way to ensure that it passes only the running instance and not new instance. For that, create a private temp var and intialize it as `this`(which means Activity) in `init()` of the class and pass it as the `instance`. This way, third will pass the running instance of the activity.

Comment: Thanks I managed to apply your solution and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data from one activity to another using extras. For example you can set some flag in first activity by doing this:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("SOME_KEY", true)
startActivity(intent)
```

Then receive the flag in onCreate of second Activity and call method if true flag is passed:

```
val flag = intent.getBooleanExtra("SOME_KEY", false)
if (flag) {
  //call method in second Activity
}
```

However you shouldn't be calling Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0) in first place. You can clear app state by just recreating Activity. Also casting to activity class is unnecessary, because you already pass activity instance to the method:

```
fun triggerRestart(context: Activity)
```

so context object is an instance of Activity and there is no reason to check and cast it. Instead of this:

```
if (context is Activity) {
  (context as Activity).finish()
}
```

just call

```
activity.finish()
```

Comment: Your answer is great and easy to understand thanks for your contribution.